# Gauge invariance of simplified weak interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, weak-interaction

I am having difficulties with a homework set. We are given the following lagrangian for a simplified weak interaction between an electron $\psi$, neutrino $\chi$, and a massive (complex) vector-boson $W^+$:

$\mathcal L = - \overline \psi (\not\partial +m_e)\psi -\chi(\not\partial + m_\nu)\chi -F^+_{\mu \nu} F^{- \mu \nu} -M_W(W^+_\mu W^{-\mu}) - g_W(\overline \psi \gamma^\mu \chi W^-_\mu + \overline\chi\gamma^\mu \psi W^+_\mu)$

where we have that $W^-=(W^+)^*$ and $F^\pm:=\partial_\mu W^\pm_\nu - \partial_\nu W^\pm$. The question is whether or not this lagrangian is gauge invariant and what this means for the degrees of freedom. Now I recognise the Proca Lagrangian inside this interaction (The terms with $F^\pm$ and $M_W$), and I know that this is not gauge invariant on its own under the transformation $W^+_\mu \mapsto W^+_\mu +\partial_\mu\alpha$ (the mass term breaks gauge invariance and revives the longitudinal degree of freedom that we lose in the massless case).

But since we have new fields to couple to I imagine that introducing a covariant derivative that replaces $\partial$ with $D = \partial + f(W^+,W^-)$ along with extra transformation rules for $\psi \mapsto e^{i\alpha} \psi$ and $\chi\mapsto e^{-i\alpha^*}\chi$ could work, but trying to work it out I still cant reconcile this transformation with the $M_W$ mass term and $g_W$ interaction terms.

Is it then possible to conclude that $\mathcal L$ has no chance of carrying gauge symmetry?

Comment: So you are seeking a nonabelian Proca Theory without extra fields?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am not sure, non-abelian gauge theory seems way too complicated since this is a problem set from an introductory course on qft. But why do you say without extra fields?